# Devportal and Publisher are redirecting to localhost

Tags: apim

After installation, there are 4 default urls. Carbon, admin, devportal and publisher. Carbon portal is working as expected. While accessing to devportal and publisher portal like "https://IP:9443/devportal", it is redirecting to "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=LiMCkQFrVQabPwGzEBvGXbD9r2wa&scope=apim:admin%20apim:api_key%20apim:app_import_export%20apim:app_manage%20apim:store_settings%20apim:sub_alert_manage%20apim:sub_manage%20apim:subscribe%20openid&state=%2F&redirect_uri=https://localhost:9443/devportal/services/auth/callback/login&prompt=none".

Tried to follow the guide to set up but those don't work until now.

Although the documents are updated for v4.2, there are some old version configuration files. So it is not working as per the document guide. I'm using below versions.

WSO2 API Manager v4.2.0
WSO2 Carbon Framework v4.8.1

For example, in the api-manager.sh file, wso2carbon.pid is referred in several places and it throws errors whenver api-manager is restarted.

if [ -e "$CARBON_HOME/wso2carbon.pid" ]; then
135   PID=`cat "$CARBON_HOME"/wso2carbon.pid`

elif [ "$CMD" = "stop" ]; then
209   export CARBON_HOME="$CARBON_HOME"
210   kill -term `cat "$CARBON_HOME"/wso2carbon.pid`
211   exit 0
212 elif [ "$CMD" = "restart" ]; then
213   export CARBON_HOME="$CARBON_HOME"
214   kill -term `cat "$CARBON_HOME"/wso2carbon.pid`
215   process_status=0
216   pid=`cat "$CARBON_HOME"/wso2carbon.pid`